# pyqt how to get previous fig manager

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 8 figures initialized as shown bellow;

```
fig = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ax_i = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ax_temp = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ax_v = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ax_fan = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

fig[0], (ax_i[0], ax_temp[0], ax_v[0], ax_fan[0]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
fig[1], (ax_i[1], ax_temp[1], ax_v[1], ax_fan[1]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
fig[2], (ax_i[2], ax_temp[2], ax_v[2], ax_fan[2]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
fig[3], (ax_i[3], ax_temp[3], ax_v[3], ax_fan[3]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
fig[4], (ax_i[4], ax_temp[4], ax_v[4], ax_fan[4]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
fig[5], (ax_i[5], ax_temp[5], ax_v[5], ax_fan[5]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
fig[6], (ax_i[6], ax_temp[6], ax_v[6], ax_fan[6]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
fig[7], (ax_i[7], ax_temp[7], ax_v[7], ax_fan[7]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
```

When I call individual figures, I want to maximize the figure before saving in .png format.
I use the following approach to maximize the figure window;

```
manager= plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.window.showMaximized()
```

The problem is, this approach works and maximizes only the last figure i.e. fig[7]

```
fig[7], (ax_i[7], ax_temp[7], ax_v[7], ax_fan[7]) = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
```

it seems the `manager` gets the configuration for the last figure.
How can i maximize the previous figures, i mean to say is there something like;

```
manager= plt.get_fig_manager(fig[i])
manager.window.showMaximized()
```

Alternatively, I want something like;

```
manager= plt.get_fig_manager(fig[i])
```

instead of:

```
manager= plt.get_current_fig_manager()
```

Else, how can I get it fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the backend you use is PyQt and you want to get all matplotlib windows then you can use the [`topLevelWidgets()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets) method:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

for window in QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
    window.showMaximized()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.